# Conditionally set a variable in cmake based on configuration

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, cmake

Is it possible to conditionally set a variable in cmake based on the config? For example, I am trying to something like:

```
set(VAR 
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:definition_for_debug>
    $<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:definition_for_rel_with_debug>
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>:definition_for_release> 
    $<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:definition_for_tight_release>
    )
```

However, when I do this, cmake returns an error where the variable is used. What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. There should be no whitespace between the different generator expressions:

```
set(VAR $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:definition_for_debug>$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:definition_for_rel_with_debug>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:definition_for_release> $<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:definition_for_tight_release>
)
```

Comment: This should not make a difference. I am able to use either method. Most likely your problem was in contents of those definition_for_*

Comment: Does not work for me, if I do:

```
set(VAR $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:1>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:2>$<$<CONFIG:Test>:3>)

message(${VAR})
```

I get `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:1>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:2>$<$<CONFIG:Test>:3>` output, like it takes literal value and does not evaluate generator expression.